# Status read failed: Connection reset by peer at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/Net/HTTP/Methods.pm line 265

Tags: laravel-4, bluehost

I am a self-learning in coding never attend a lesson. This issue is quite annoying as i find nothing clue in internet. Recently my website get somethings wrong suddenly when i submit any form with post method. I cannot confirm this is a server problem or coding problem (as laravel can spot the bug i made but nothing wrong).

Status read failed: Connection reset by peer at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/Net/HTTP/Methods.pm line 265.

The issue occurred only when using mobile network. I tried:

1. Together with my computer (boardband) and mobile (mobile network). Only mobile cannot process.
2. the same mobile first with mobile network -> cannot work. 
   Change to WIFI signal -> work. 
   Change back to mobile network -> cannot work again.
3. Two to three mobiles with different networks. All shows the same above.

Anyway to debug or find out what happen? Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Please provide your code so we could see what is wrong.

Comment: Sorry, i have no hints where it get wrong. As it is related to any post method form submission. Any hints for me which part of coding should i post ?